# How i can achieve relational data using Hibernate Search?

Tags: jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using JPARepository, I chose Hibernate Search for implementing search functionality.

Here is link : http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/

Using an EntityManager (JPA) to rebuild an index

**FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
ftem.createIndexer().startAndWait();**

Suppose I have Two Entity classes **Company.java** & **Employee.java**.

Employees(e_id) saved under Company(c_id) and relation stored in another table "company_employee".

I want to implement search on only those employees(not all employees of other companies) which are associated with company account.

for eg: **select e_id from company_employee where c_id = ?**
Now assume i getting 3 employees of company and want to fetch the all record of these 3 employees and not others.

Comment: try to use @IndexedEmbedded annotation.

Comment: BoutayaBilal thanks, 
yeah i am using this @IndexedEmbedded annotation, suppose fetch company employees data using wlidcard and query is " luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name").matching("m*").createQuery(); " 
How I fetch those employees(not all employees of other companies) which are associated  with company account.

Answer (score 0):

You fetch company and not employee like this :

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Company.class).get();
```

In your lucene query :

luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("employees.employeeName").matching("m*").createQuery()

Employees is the field annotatted with @IndexedEmbedded.

```
public class Company {
...
@IndexedEmbedded
private List<Employee> employees; 
...
}
```

You will get a company with only its employees and not all the employees. (I don't know if you have to use eager fetch or not)
Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanks @Bilal , I wil try this.

Comment: I got my expected result :) just using setCriteria() with lucene query.
Query fullTextQuery = getFullTextEntityManager().createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery).setCriteriaQuery(criteria);

Comment: It is not recommended to use ORM Criteria queries in conjunction with Hibernate Search Lucene queries. This is not supported. Only specifying the fetch mode via a Critria is supported. See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_building_a_hibernate_search_query